# Binding to Xamarin Forms FlexLayout.Basis

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a page in my Xamarin.Forms application where I'm attempting to bind a relative size (25%, 50%, etc) to the basis of an item within a FlexLayout, but can't get it to work successfully.

My XAML:

```
 ...
 <FlexLayout x:Name="Flex"
             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedSideBarItem.Items}"
             AlignItems="Start"
             JustifyContent="Start"
             Direction="Row"
             AlignContent="Start"
             Wrap="Wrap">
         <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Button FlexLayout.Basis="{Binding ItemBasis}"
                         Title="{Binding Name}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
 </FlexLayout>
 ...
```

I can't seem to find any examples, and the documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about binding to a Basis property from a view model. My initial attempt was attempting to bind a string to the to the FlexLayout.Basis. Like so:

```
...
private string _itemBasis;
public string ItemBasis
{
    get => _itemBasis;
    set
    {
        _itemBasis = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemBasis));
    }
}
...

public void SetBasis()
{
    ItemBasis = "25%"; // or any other percentage.
    // Does not work!
}

...
```

The above doesn't work. It appears that the basis is never set, so the default is used.

I should note that binding to a basis **does works** when using an absolute size (250, 500, etc) (i.e. it's not an issue with my bindings). Like so:

```
...
private int_itemBasis;
public int ItemBasis
{
    get => _itemBasis;
    set
    {
        _itemBasis = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemBasis));
    }
}
...

public void SetBasis()
{
    ItemBasis = 250; // or any other absolute value.
    // Works!
}

...
```

Any guidance would be appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML TypeConverters are not called when a value is set via binding, so the [default FlexBasis TypeConverter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FlexEnums.cs#L207) is not applied when you try to bind the string "25%".

Fortunately the `FlexBasisTypeConverter` class is public so you can use it in your own converter class like so:

```
public class StringToFlexBasisConverter: IValueConverter
{
    private readonly FlexBasis.FlexBasisTypeConverter _converter = new FlexBasis.FlexBasisTypeConverter();
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            return _converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(stringValue);
        }
        return new FlexBasis();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks stranger. Picking this answer as accepted. The example is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The type for the `Basis` property is `FlexBasis`
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FlexEnums.cs#L58

If you bind it to a string is not going to work (unless using a converter).
Try to modify your bindable property to `FlexBasis` and assign the value like this:

```
ItemBasis = new FlexBasis(.5f, true);
```

The first parameter is the length, the second is the "relative" flag. Setting it to `true`  means that you are using a percentage value.

Comment: Much appreciate. Great answer.